# Cannot connect to SSH after installing SSL cetificates through Certbot

Tags: ssh, https, apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

Recently I  installed SSL cetificates through Certbot on apache2 server, and my website can be accessed through HTTPS. I have also enabled redirect to HTTPS. But I can no longer connect to the server via SSH. What can I do now?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should ask questions like this on [unix.se], [sf], or [su]. When you do, you should describe exactly what changes you made on the server and what happens when you try to connect to the server through ssh. There isn't really any useful information in this question in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow the 22/tcp while setting up the ssl certificates.
To do this, you have to check if `ufw status`is `active`.
If it is `inactive`, then let you allow `active`.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw default deny
```

And then execute `sudo ufw status` command and you have to see following.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

If you can't see the `22/tcp` is allowed, then allow the `ssh`.

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Then you will be able to connect to the server using `SSH` after installing ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

While setting up, if the UFW is set to allow port  80(HTTP) and 443(HTTPS), but not 22(SSH), then HTTP and HTTPS would work fine but not SSH. This means that you can get locked out of your server if you don't allow connecting to it via port 22 (SSH).